# How to set a list as the index of an existing pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an existing pandas dataframe, which looks something like:

```
    Gr          R           B           Gb
0   1.537037    1.733333    1.400000    1.537037
1   1.657952    1.706522    1.650407    1.713024
2   1.670982    1.690476    1.626263    1.661202
3   1.689229    1.683761    1.607143    1.676923
...
```

I have a separate list, where the length of the list is equal to the number of rows in the above dataframe. Something like:

`separate_list = ['a','b','c',....]`

How can I make the separate list to be the index of the above dataframe, replacing the default index (0,1,2,...)? All I can find are ways to set an **existing column** to the index.

Thank you.

Comment: So you want 0,1,2 replaced with a,b,c...? does `df.index = separate_list` help?

Comment: Yes, but the values are not a,b,c... in actual.

Comment: So what are they?

Comment: I don't think that's important... the values can be anything, they have the same length as the dataframe. I just want to fit the entire list in.

Comment: read the first comment. That should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply making your list a column of the DataFrame (`df['new_index'] = separate_list`) and *then* setting to be the index should work.

Answer (score 2):

A pandas df has a `set_index` method that allows you to make an existing column or a separate series the new df index.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

Answer (score 1):

Dataframe.set_index() will help you to do the same. 
For your example, it will be,

```
DF = pd.DataFrame(#Your Dataframe)
DF.set_index(keys=separate_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `DF` be your `pandas.DataFrame` and `index_list` be a flat list with same size as DF rows, something like `index_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...]`:

```
DF.set_index(keys = [index_list])
```

will do it. And note that index_list must be enclosed between brackets in this case.

Alternatively, if `index_list = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...]]` you should use:

```
DF.set_index(keys = index_list)
```

and now, there is no need to enclose it, that's the way it goes with Shah's example above.