# Set a list as the index of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a list called: `sens_fac = [0.8, 1, 1.2]`, and a dataframe `df` defined this way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(sens_fac)),columns=range(len(factors)))
```

However, I want to modify the index. I know I can do this in the definition, and it works.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index=sens_fac,columns=range(len(factors)))
```

But what if I want to modify the index after it was created? I tried doing this

`df.set_index(sens_fac)`

But I get this error:

`KeyError: 'None of [0.8, 1.2] are in the columns'`

Comment: just check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59726828/how-to-set-a-list-as-the-index-of-an-existing-pandas-dataframe

Comment: You can't use `set_index` unless you first create a dataframe. It's not entirely clear what your expected output is, but what about `df = pd.DataFrame(index=sens_fact)`?

Comment: @G.Anderson the `df` was already created (I modified the question to make it clear), but still I can not assign that list called `sens_fac` as the index

Answer (score 0):

You only call the `set_index` method on an existing `pandas.DataFrame` object of the same length as your index (so it must not be empty). **But** there is an `index` argument in the constructor:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sens_fact = np.random.rand(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=sens_fact)
```

I you want to **manipulate an existing** `pandas.DataFrame` than `pandas.DataFrame.set_index()` is the correct method but it expects the *name of a column* of the table. So you go with:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(sens_fact, columns={'sens_fact'})
print(df) # dataframe with standard enumerated indices
df.set_index('sens_fact', inplace=True)
print(df) # dataframe with no columns an non-standard index
```

Or you can just manipulate the index directly:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(sens_fact)))
df.index = sens_fact
```

Comment: The DataFrame was already created. I edited the question as it wasn't totally clear.

Comment: That makes it even simpler =) I added the options you have @nekovolta